# Why I do not see GraphQL App when using APIRouter from FastAPI

Tags: graphql, fastapi, graphene-python

I cannot understand, why I do not see an interface like [this](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/graphql/#check-it)
when using APIRouter from FastAPI.

My service looks like:

```
class GraphqlService(graphene.ObjectType):
    hello = graphene.String(name=graphene.String(default_value="stranger"))

    @staticmethod
    def resolve_hello(self, info, name):
        return "Hello " + name
```

And view like this:

```
router = APIRouter()

graphql_app = GraphQLApp(schema=graphene.Schema(query=GraphqlService), executor_class=AsyncioExecutor)

@router.get('/db_article', response_model=Union[Article, ArticleNotFound])
async def db_articles(request):
      return await graphql_app.handle_graphql(request)
```

However, when I go to http://localhost:8089/myAPI/v1/db_article,
I get an error: `{"detail":[{"loc":["query","request"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}`

Comment: I am not familiar with fastapi and graphene-python. But in most cases the grapql libs have their own servlet under `yourhost:yourport/graphql`

Comment: You have a `request` argument in your function signature. If this is supposed to be the request coming into FastAPI, you need to type it as such (`from fastapi import Request`, `async def db_articles(request: Request)`, otherwise FastAPI assumes it is a query parameter automagically. However, it's hard to say if this is what you want when you've included a service that you don't use in your view code, and that doesn't have the method name you call in the view. If you read the example code you've linked, they register the route directly form the app and not through a secondary view.

Comment: @MatsLindh it actually helped! Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "you've included a service that you don't use in your view code, and that doesn't have the method name you call in the view"? I think I do use my service when I have `Schema(query=GraphqlService)`..is it wrong? Sorry, I am totally new to that thing..

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread that line. That's absolutely correct.

Comment: Do you want to copy your comment to answers, so i will accept it? and actually something still is not correct with this setup...but I'll make a new question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ou have a request argument in your function signature. If this is supposed to be the request coming into FastAPI, you need to type it as such:

```
from fastapi import Request

....

async def db_articles(request: Request):
```

.. otherwise FastAPI assumes it is a query parameter automagically. If you read the example code you've linked, they register the route directly form the app and not through a secondary view.

```
app = FastAPI()
app.add_route("/", GraphQLApp(schema=graphene.Schema(query=Query)))
```